# Как называются жители Кыргызстана?

Tags: этноним, ономастика

Раньше это была республика Киргизия, и жители назывались, соответственно, киргизы. Сейчас же это страна Кыргызстан, но как называются ее жители? Кыргызы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен не совсем четко - речь идет о жителях Кыргызстана или коренной нации? Отвечу на оба вопроса:

1. Если речь идет о жителях страны (без учета их национальности), то надо говорить (и они так и говорят) кыргызстанцы
2. Если речь идет о коренных жителях - то тут есть некая тонкость. Они сами себя всегда звали `кыргыз` (сорок девушек или племен, которые по преданию были родоначальниками народа). В советское время прижился упрощенный для русского уха этноним `киргиз`. Из опыта своего общения с киргизами: они абсолютно нормально воспринимают и `кыргыз` и `киргиз` так что если мы будем их звать киргизами это будет вполне комфортно как для русской речи, так и для их восприятия. Мы же зовем немцев `немец`, хотя они сами себя называют `Deutsch` - `дойч`

Comment: Вообще-то, если судить по формулировке, автора интересуют прежде всего именно жители. Но я о другом. Стоит ли в угоду непонятно каким политичским веяньям изобретать совершенно непринимаемых русским ухом и языком лингвистических уродцев? Я понимаю - топонимы, в них для передачи точного звучания, возможно, имеет смысл пожертвовать родной фонетикой, но в нарицательных словах?! Вы же сам пишете, немцам фиолетово, что их Дойчлянд называется у нас Германия.  
А вдруг они дейсвительно переименуются?  Будем величать их Кыргызжор(ц)ами? (жер/йер - земля, Кыргызжер - Земля Киргизов).

Comment: Вы - не будете. А я - буду. Если вдруг встречу, что весьма сомнительно ... ;-))

Comment: Вопрос интересный - я думаю все дело в привычке. Если они будут переименовываться каждые 10 лет, то должны же будут понимать что их будут называть как попало. Ну вон как Камбоджа: то ее звали Камбоджа, то Кампучия, то еще как то. В итоге все зовут ее каждый по своему и все прекрасно понимают.

Answer (score 1):

Названия жителей или представителей национальности, образованные непосредственно от Кыргызстан, словарями не фиксируются. Киргизы, имхо, вполне ныне употребительно. Как и Киргизия. Кыргызстан - это уже политический новояз.

ЗЫ Они там переименовываться собрались. В "Кыргызжер". Если состоится, именовать их кыргызжорами, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Киргизы - это все-таки этнос. Наверное, кыргызстанцы. Для русского уха звучит сложно, но как-то же надо отличать одно от другого?

Представляю, что меня (жительницу Татарии) назвали бы татаркой... Может, еще и поэтому мне больше нравится название республики "Татарстан". Хотя слова "татарстанец", а особенно "татарстанка", наверное, пока не прижились.

Comment: Это очень спорный и "больной" вопрос. Четкое разделение между этносом и жителями можно указать только в некоторых случаях. Латыши-латвийцы, мальгаши-малагасийцы и т.п. А тут ещё вопрос гражданства примешивается...
Для Татарии/Татарстана этот вопрос так остро не стоит за отсутствием полной государственности. А вот для Киргизии... Нет, я определенно против погони за парадом национального самосознания.

Comment: Хорошо, разрешаю Вам быть против ;-))  

Ой, что-то "Галактионом" повеяло: он нам многое милостиво разрешал...